# How can I enable DEP/NX and ASLR on a Delphi 2006 or earlier executable?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

[Delphi 2007 (and newer) supports](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/michaeldevery/2007/04/05/33777) enabling DEP and ASLR via any of these three techniques:

- add the command-line switch `–dynamicbase` when compiling with dcc32
- add the preprocessor command `{$DYNAMICBASE ON}` to the source code
- manually OR in the bit in the header, with `{$SETPEOPTFLAGS $40}` in the source code

I'd like to be able to do the same thing with Delphi 2006 and C++ Builder 2006 (aka BDS 2006). Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Set PE flags**

You can use `{$SetPEOptFlags $40}` to set the DEP flag, and `{$SetPEOptFlags $100}` to set the ASLR flag. To set both use `{$SetPEOptFlags $140}`.

If you have a version of Delphi with the necessary definitions in the Windows.pas unit you can use the much more readable:

```
{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT or
    IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE }
```

Typically you include the `$SetPEOptFlags` setting in the .dpr file. And so you need to make sure that `Windows` is in the .dpr file uses clause for these `IMAGE_XXX` constants to be available.

**Set DEP policy at runtime**

For versions that don't support PE flag based approaches you can call this function early in your app's initialization:

```
procedure EnableDEP;
const
  PROCESS_DEP_ENABLE: DWORD=$00000001;
var
  SetProcessDEPPolicy: function(dwFlags: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  SetProcessDEPPolicy := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(kernel32), 
     'SetProcessDEPPolicy');
  if Assigned(SetProcessDEPPolicy) then begin
    //don't bother checking for errors since we don't need to know if it fails
    SetProcessDEPPolicy(PROCESS_DEP_ENABLE);
  end;
end;
```

This will work for any version of Delphi.

You cannot set the ASLR flag at runtime since it influences how the module is loaded. So ASLR can only be set using PE flags.

**Modifying PE flags for very old versions of Delphi**

Older versions of Delphi do not support `$SetPEFlags` and `$SetPEOptFlags`. For such versions you need to use an external tool to modify the executable post-build. When I originally wrote this answer I assumed that `EDITBIN` from the MS toolchain would do the job. For DEP it will suffice, using the `/NXCOMPAT` option. For ASLR you will need to use a different PE flag editor. My websearch revealed `peflags` from cygwin.

```
peflags --dynamicbase=true --nxcompat=true MyApp.exe
```

I'm sure there are other PE flag editing options available.

Comment: Couple of notes: Editbin.exe is part of all versions of visual studio. The needed /nxcompat option is in VS 2008 and up. Note that on a stock install of VS 2010, editbin.exe may throw errors related to missing dlls. I resolved this by simply copying in the dlls to the dir where editbin.exe resides.

Comment: @Jonesome Copying the DLLs is not the solution. Use the vcvarsall.bat script, or the more modern setenv.cmd script to setup the necessary paths.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right, the bat file should be used... but copying the dlls does work... (have done it more than once...)

Comment: @Jonesome I know. I used to do it that way too until I worked out the official way to do it!  ;-)

Answer (score 7):

‘{$DYNAMICBASE ON}’ is new in Delphi2007, ‘{$SETPEOPTFLAGS $40}' was an existing directive: [info](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2007/03/review-delphi-2007-for-win32-beta-part_06.html)

{$SetPEOptFlags $40} works in Delphi2006

Comment: I think its better to use named contant `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE`

Comment: Const IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE is not available in D2006, you have to define it self.

Comment: @ArjenvanderSpek Is that so? Doesn't adding Windows to uses make it available?

Comment: @DavidHeffeman: just (re)tried, const is not available, at least not in mine version of 2006