# COM Object compiled in Delphi 2006: How to DEP enable it?

Tags: delphi, ocx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable DEP/NX and ASLR on a Delphi 2006 or earlier executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066266/how-can-i-enable-dep-nx-and-aslr-on-a-delphi-2006-or-earlier-executable)

We have a very large Delphi 2006 project that we do not want to migrate to the current delphi (because it would take a month of work....). This project compiles to an in process COM binary (ocx).

DEP has caused a lot of headache, because .NET and VC devs all default to DEP=True.

**The Question:** Can we make the OCX DEP-ified?

**Background:**
DEP is a process level attribute. A non-DEP process will load DLLs and OCXs that are either DEP or non-DEP. However a DEP process will refuse to load non-DEP dlls and OCXs with an ugly "inaccessible memory location" error. This is why, when creating native dlls and in process OCXs that will be consumed by other devs, DEP is a very important fact of life.

I see the thread here:
[How can I enable DEP/NX and ASLR on a Delphi 2006 or earlier executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066266/how-can-i-enable-dep-nx-and-aslr-on-a-delphi-2006-or-earlier-executable)

But it seems to be talking about enabling DEP at the process level (e.g. in an exe created by Delphi 2006).

What do we do to DLLs and OCXs compiled by Delphi, that will run in-process, that is about to be loaded into a DEP=true process?

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't DEP a process-wide setting?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, it is process wide. It is set at the exe level. However, if an ocx is not DEP enabled, a DEP process will refuse to load it. I am expanding the OP to discuss this.

Comment: In the article you've linked, one of the answer is to add `{$SetPEOptFlags $40}` (or thought digging a bit more, `{$SetPEOptFlags $140}` to add the NX flag too) in your project file. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Jonesome the OP is you (the Original Poster), I think you are expanding _the question_, as you cannot expand yourself to include any more info ;)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do not believe it is a dupe. The thread you ref (which I also ref) looks to be talking to how to set it for an exe created by delphi. What I need to set, in a D2006 env, is the part of the PE file called "DLL Characterstics" (per MS PE doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/gg463125 ). It is not clear that the other SO thread is speaking to this area of the PE file.

Comment: It's exactly the same for DLL and EXE. Both are PE files. Use any of the solutions from the other question and you are fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks! We are looking into this! (editbin.exe is fine with us).... Will take us a day or two to get it all work it through!