# How to enable ASLR for a lazarus exe project?

Tags: pascal, lazarus, aslr

executable files on windows have a `.reloc` section which stores information to rebase the image. But EXE built by lazarus doesn't have that. How I enable dynamic base on a lazarus project if I really need ASLR?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8066266/62576) help?

Comment: Probably not. Very Delphi specific. Further the absence of relocation tables is a show stopper.

Comment: If I were you I'd look at the command line being passed to the compiler. Reference the fpc docs http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/usersu15.html I bet it is disabling reloc section. Change that and you will be on your way.

Comment: -WB  -WR.  it seems. No experience though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Editbin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d25ddyfc.aspx) tool with /DYNAMICBASE or /HIGHENTROPYVA parameter to edit your executable .