# How to enable SafeSEH, CFG (Control Flow Guard) in Delphi 10.4?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

Is there any way to enable the SafeSEH, CFG flags in Delphi 10.4?
I have enabled the ASLR flag using the `{$SETPEOPTFLAGS $140}` command.

Comment: Linking possible source of why you did that: [How can I enable DEP/NX and ASLR on a Delphi 2006 or earlier executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8066804/4299358)

Comment: Modern Delphi versions support ASLR as a linker option in the project options, you don't need to resort to using `{$SETPEOPTFLAGS}` to enable it manually. As for SafeSEH and CFG, they require compiler/linker support to setup additional data/code in the exe, so it's not enough to just enable their flags in the PE header. Delphi does not support SafeSEH or CFG at this time. But there is a `SetProcessValidCallTargets()` API you can call in your own code to implement CFG manually, at least.

Comment: @RemyLebeau how to call SetProcessValidCallTargets() ?